# Control indexing for ndb.Expando model properties

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have an ndb.Model that contains an ndb.Expando model as a structured property, and I'd like to be able to control indexing, but I cannot find anything in the documentation about it.

```
class MyModel2(ndb.Expando):
    pass

class MyModel(ndb.Model):
    sub_entity = ndb.StructuredProperty(MyModel2)
```

The only piece of documentation I can find is the following:

> You can specify the usual property options for structured properties
>   (except indexed)

I assume this is because the actual indexing should be specified on a per-property basis in the embedded model. However, it is not clear how to enable or disable indexing on Expando model properties.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the _properties object to set if a field should be indexed or not.  E.g.

```
a = MyModel2()
a.value = '3'
a._properties['value']._indexed = False
```

You can find the docs on [_properties](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/modelclass#intro_properties) have more details.

Comment: This is great. I was looking through that documentation and none of the examples include setting properties, only viewing them. Do you have any references to setting them explicitly.

Comment: Cool. I may dig into the Python SDK to see if I can see anything, but this is good enough for me. Thanks.